# How do I wait for an element to load on second page before clicking on it with my Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await

My chrome extension is an automation tool that clicks through several buttons on several pages.

I use this function to wait for a pre-determined time before clicking on the button on the second page.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((accept) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            accept();
        }, ms);
    });
}
```

This function gets all the items on my profile page

```
function getAllItems() {
    return document.getElementsByClassName('Item');
```

I then click on each item and click the save button on the item page

```
async function main() {
    // Gets all items on my page.
    let allItems = getAllItems();

    for (let i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++ ) {
      let currentItem = allItems[i];
      
      // click on first item on page
      currentItem.click();

      // wait for 3 seconds in order to get save button to load
      await sleep(3000);
      function getSaveButton() {
        return getButtonByClassName('Save');

      let saveButton = getSaveButton();
      saveButton.click();
      }
}
```

My problem is that sometimes the 3000 seconds is not enough time for the save button to load and the loop ends.

I don't want to put the pause up to anything significantly higher, as obviously that slows the whole process down.

Comment: What do you want to happen instead of waiting? Are you looking for a way to "react" to the button appearing?

Comment: At the moment I'm waiting a pre-determined amount of time (3000 ms in the code above) before running the "getSaveButton" function and clicking on the save button. 

I want to wait as long as it takes for the save button to appear before running anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in your comments that you want to wait for the button to appear, as long as necessary, you should use a setInterval to check the webpage once in a given interval if the button has appeared - so in your case:

```js
function main() {
    // Gets all items on my page.
    let allItems = getAllItems();

    for (let i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++ ) {
      let currentItem = allItems[i];
      
      // click on first item on page
      currentItem.click();

      // check every 3 seconds if the save button is loaded. When loaded, click it.
      const intervalId = setInterval(() {
        const saveButton = getButtonByClassName('Save');
        if (saveButton) {
            saveButton.click();
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
      }, 3000);
}
```

You can probably use a smaller interval obviously :). Also note that in this case, the function is no longer "async".